# Is there a difference between Url.Content("~/...") and "~/" for urls in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm dealing with a web application that resides within a subdirectory on a domain, and I'm attempting to discern the most idiomatic way of inserting a proper URL into an `img` tag. While the following both produce the same HTML on the client machine, I'm not sure which is more "correct"

- `<img src="~/Content/images/blah.png" />`
- `<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/blah.png")`

Both of these produce an absolute path of `/subfolder/Content/images/blah.png`, so both work, but I'm curious which one is the right way of doing it.

**Is there any difference between these two approaches (for example, is one being resolved by a different mechanism than the other?), or is the former just syntactic sugar for the latter?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With MVC4 you no longer need `@Url.Content`

> If Razor detects ~/ it would created an output identical to
>   @Url.Content.

http://www.beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-razor-changes.html

Comment: Thanks; this is exactly what I'm looking for. As soon as the timer's up, you'll get the check.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work within a ViewComponent authored in a Razor Pages project.  Still need Url.Content().  Are you aware of anything to make it work *without* the Url.Content so my code could be the same 'everywhere'?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is "more correct". I would use the shorthand since Razor now supports it.

Comment: Thanks; I wasn't sure if there was a difference between the two (say, for example, one was being resolved by some sort of internal IIS mechanism to use the application root and the other was using something specific to ASP.NET MVC).

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing string through controller, you need to use @url.content().
but it you are passing path directly in .cshtml, no need to use @url.content().

Ex. No need.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/blah.png")  />
```

NEED

```
@ViewBag.ImagePath = "~/Content/images/blah.png";
<img src="@Url.Content(@ViewBag.ImagePath)" />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work within a ViewComponent authored in a Razor Pages project. Still need Url.Content(). Is this same problem you are mentioning?  My model for the ViewComponent as a ImagePath property, so I had to do `src="@Url.Content( Model.ImagePath )"`.  If this is same issue you are describing, where did you find documentation explaining this?  Thanks.